# Обучение модели без учителя на нескольких текстовых признаках

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, текст, nlp

Предположим, что есть 3 признака, которые содержат текст. Текст является произвольным(не категориальным). Скажем эти признаки могут являться комментариями, содержанием и т.п. Но возникает проблема обучения модели. Возможно, это глупый вопрос, но как подать сразу несколько признаков на обучение?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Образование DataFrame'a для обучения
data = df[["текстовый_признак1", "текстовый_признак2", "текстовый_признак3"]]

# Векторизатор
tfvec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words)
text_vec = tfvec.fit_transform(data)

# Обучение модели
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, random_state = 142)
kmeans.fit(text_vec)
kmeans_pred = kmeans.fit_predict(text_vec)
```

При попытке использовать данный код получается разреженная матрица 3x3, хотя `data` является полноценным DataFrame'ом со всеми необходимыми данными, но, когда подаётся 1 признак, то разреженная матрица получается ожидаемого размера(1367x460) и тогда уже можно производить обучение

Comment: тензор какой размерности вы ожидаете получить на выходе `tfvec.fit_transform(data)` если `data` содержит 3 столбца??

Comment: @MaxU, если под тензором вы подразумеваете разреженную матрицу, то, возможно, объединённую этих столбцов. Или это так не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если словари фич пересекаются, то простая конкатенация признаков может быть не лучшим решением, ведь может оказаться важным, в каком именно из признаков оказалось то или иное слово, а при конкатенации признаков эта информация теряется. Объединять фичи можно и просто соединив столбцы вышедшие из трансформеров после преобразования отдельно каждой фичи (для последующего вертикального соединения столбцов есть методы и в `Pandas` и в `Numpy`), а можно использовать функцию [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) из `Sklearn` специально предназначенную для соединения нескольких фич в процессе обработки входных данных.

Пример из документации:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, TruncatedSVD
union = FeatureUnion([("pca", PCA(n_components=1)),
                      ("svd", TruncatedSVD(n_components=2))])
X_new = union.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 3):

Судя по ответу из комментария, вы хотите объединить все текстовые признаки в один.

Так и сделайте:

```
text = (df["текстовый_признак1"]
        + " " + df["текстовый_признак2"]
        + " " + df["текстовый_признак3"])

# Векторизатор
tfvec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = stop_words)
text_vec = tfvec.fit_transform(text)

...
```

Comment: И это правильное использование признаков DataSet'a для обучения или есть ещё какие-нибудь методы, которые позволяют подать признаки в модель?

Comment: @EUG217, все зависит от данных и от задачи, которую вы перед собой ставите ;)